# where conditon to get date in two columns familyno and date

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public class UserSearchDAO {


public ArrayList searchRecords(UserDTO udto) throws SQLException{

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/msdb","root","root");
    udto.getDate();
    }
    //elseif(udto.getDate()!=null && !udto.getDate().equals("")){
        //query = query+ "where date="+udto.getDate();

    System.out.println(query);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();




}
```

//This is the DAO layer to get the records in familyno and date field. could  you please help me how to write the proper query.i am new database.

query = query+ " where familyno="+udto.getFamilyno(), udto.getDate();

Comment: First thing to fix: stop putting values straight into your SQL. Use a `PreparedStatement`, and set parameters on it instead. That might fix the problem already - it's hard to tell as you've *just* dumped code into your question, with no description of what's going wrong.  (My guess is that it's a compile-time error, because the `, udto.getDate()` part of your statement makes it look like you think you're calling a method, but you're not.) We won't be able to help you without more information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: (Additionally, you should start using generics - `List<UserVO>` etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

General Format,

```
query =select * from  table_name where table_col1="+getvalue1()+" && table_col2="+getvalue2()+";
```

in order your database,

```
query="select * from  userVO where familyno="+udto.getFamilyno()+" && date="+udto.getDate()+";";
```

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a query, use parametrized statements (`PreparedStatement`).

Comment: Your query is ok for me.Thank you